# How to synchronize a code which is deployed on a cluster?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, synchronization, locking, ejb

We have a stateless ejb which persists some data in an object oriented database. Unfortunately, today our persistence object does not have a unique key due to some unknown reason and altering the PO is also not possible today.

So we decided to synchronize the code. Then we check if there is an object already persisted with the name(what we consider should be unique). Then we decide to persist or not.

Later we realized that the code is deployed on a cluster which has three jboss instances.

Can anyone please suggest an idea which does not allow to persist objects with the same name.

Comment: Do the Jboss instances connect to a single database?

Comment: Yes, all jboss instances connect to the same database

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single database behind the JBoss cluster you can just apply a unique contraint to the column for example (I am assuming its an SQL database):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (column_name);
```

Then in the application code you may want to catch the SQL exception and let the user know they need to try again or whatever.

Update:

If you cannot alter the DB schema then you can achieve the same result by performing a SELECT query before insert to check for duplicate entries, if you are worried about 2 inserts happening at the same time you can look at applying a WRITE_LOCK to the row in question

Comment: Unfortunately today we cannot update the table as you said and we want to do it through our application only. We have plan to alter the PO but not now because of some constraints on OO databases

Comment: Many thanks for the idea. I will check with the database team if we can apply a ROW LOCK in object oriented databases. We use Versant OODB.